# Would updating return types from `any` to specific types be a breaking change?

Tags: typescript, semantic-versioning

Suppose an API client returned `Promise<any>` from all its methods. Then, it's updated to return specific types instead.

Would this call for a `major` version bump or a `minor` version bump under semantic versioning?

**Note**: Some users were already overriding `Promise<any>` to more specific types, which may be different than the types we're planning to release. Would this be a breaking change for them?

**Note2**: I'm very familiar with JavaScript and semantic versioning, just new-ish to TypeScript so thanks for the help!

Comment: As your users will have to change their code, I think it is a breaking change.

Comment: Thanks @Grabofus, that's where I was leaning but lack of TypeScript expertise led me to ask. 